# Move a page to the end of the PDF

Tags: pdf, documentation, doxygen

I have a \page in Doxygen which has some non-code information in it.

Doxygen generates a fresh page for it and it's working great. However, since this page is an appendix, I'd like to have it at the end of the PDF document.

Is there any way to instruct Doxygen to do this without having to manually editing the latex sources each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little rusty on Doxygen but I recall there's no explicit way to steer Doxygen to do this. However, experiment with changing the order in which files are listed in the INPUT statement in the doxyfile. If that has an effect, it may mean you have to split your appendix into a separate file so it can be listed at the end of the INPUT.